# Input select product then load product data in an update form codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I'm currently creating a item/product update form on codeigniter. To match the product that I want to edit I use an input select that does load all the products available in the database.

After the user selects the product and then clicks on submit, the function will load all the product data in the update form.

The issue is that I don't know how to pass the input value variable and get the product data in the form **without reloading the page** (since its currently on a div tab).

My current model:

```
function editarProducto()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('productoID');;
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('items');
    return $query->result();
}
```

View (here I've the select "productoID" that will retrieve the products from the database, the idea is that after selecting the product to post the valueid to the model "editarProducto"):

```
...<form id="SelectProd-form" method="post">
                                <select id="productoID" name="productoID" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($editarID as $key => $value) {
                                        echo "<option value='".$value->id."'>".$value->nombre."</option>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <button id="botonSelectProd" type="submit" class="form-group" name="submit">Seleccionar</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="editarProducto">
                    <form id="editarProducto-form" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/editarProducto'); ?>" method="post">
                        <div id="msjRegistro" class="login-form-main-message"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-forward fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre del producto" value="<?php echo set_value('nombre'); ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="precio" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Precio</label>
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-dollar fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="number" min="0.00" max="100000.00" step="0.01" placeholder="Ingresa el precio en pesos" class="form-control" name="precio" value="<?php echo set_value('precio'); ?>"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>...
```

Comment: AJAX is your friend, here is a lot to study: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Answer (score 0):

1. Generally, on select change, or after clicking `#botonSelectProd` you use ajax to post an id from the .val() of `#productoID` to a controller function that interacts with `editarProducto()`.
2. Use the same .val() and add it to the end of your form action so you know what item you want to update and you can retrieve it in your controller like: `$this->input->get('id')`
3. Then you send back a JSON response by encoding an array like `array('field_name_1'=>'field_value_1')` .etc.
4. Using $.each you can return populate each of the inputs by name from your JSON response and presto. Your update form is populated.

At that point you have to rethink using `set_value()` and `validation_errors()` as those require page reload. You could return validation errors in json form and repopulate the submitted form values also with json, but that is more work if the only ajax you need is the selectbox.